# Solving differential equation for position of an object

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a problem that should be very easy but I might be doing something wrong :(

I want to calculate the movement of an object in orbit (to the force field depends on the position). To simplify, I will consider that is only moving parallel to the force field, no rotation around the planet and therefore no centripetal force :)

I want to obtain the equation of position as a function of time, so given some initial conditions $x_{0} and v_{0}$ I can calculate the position in any moment t.

I ended up with a differential equation, but I'm having troubles calculating the constants from the initial conditions.

Here's my steps:

$$F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

$$F = ma = m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$

Combining both equations:

$$\frac{GM}{r^2} = \frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$

Rearranging things and applying double integrals:

$$\int_{}^{} \int_{}^{} GMdtdt = \int_{}^{} \int_{}^{} r^2 drdr$$

$$\int_{}^{} (GMt + A)dt = \int_{}^{} (\frac{r^3}{3} + B)dr$$

$$GM\frac{t^2}{2} + At + C = \frac{r^4}{12} + Br + D$$

$$\frac{GM}{2}t^2 + At + \frac{1}{12}r^4 + Br + E = 0$$

Is it OK so far? I combined the constants C and D into a single one (E = C - D)

The first thing that I see here is that I have 3 unknowns (A,B and E) and only two initial condition parameters ($x_{0}$ and $v_{0}$).

Also A is multiplying t so it will be cancelled when applying initial conditions :(

Using $r_{0}$:

$$\frac{1}{12}r_{0}^4 + Br_{0} + E = 0$$

Using $v_{0}$:

How do I use $v_{0}$ in an equation that only has r?

I'm stuck here, I tried writing r as vt so I have some v, but then since v is multiplying t it will be cancelled in initial conditions (when t=0)

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not replace the second order differential $d^2r$ with the square of the first order differential $(dr)^2$. What you can do is either multiply with $\dot r$ to get
$$
-GM\frac{d}{dt}\frac1r = \frac{GM\dot r}{r^2}=\dot r\ddot r=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot r^2}2\implies \dot r^2 = C-\frac{2GM}r
$$
or assume that $\dot r=u(r)$, leading to $\ddot r=u'(r)u(r)$ and insert this to get essentially the same equation.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your development. In my development I am solving a second derivative by integrating twice. In your equation you start with a -GM$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{r}$. I don't even see where the negative symbol comes, where the other r in denomitator goes (the gravitational force equation has a r^2 in the denominator) and where the 1/dt comes from.

Comment: Of course you can try to integrate $$\int_{s=0}^t\int_{\tau=0}^s GM\,d\tau\,ds=\int_{s=0}^t\int_{\tau=0}^s r(\tau)^2\ddot r(\tau)\,d\tau\,ds=\int_0^t(t-\tau)r(\tau)^2\ddot r(\tau)\,d\tau,$$ but in no way does the second derivative resolve in the manner you are proposing. You are somehow proposing that $\ddot r(\tau)\,d\tau\,ds=\dot r(s)\dot r(\tau)\,d\tau\,ds$, which does not make any sense.